# Is gcc C compiler written in C itself?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

Is gcc C compiler written in C itself ? Or is it written in Assembly ? If the compiler is written in C, then what is the compiler used to compile the compiler code ?

Comment: Yes it is (mostly). Of course, one needs a C compiler to compile C so, as with most compilers, there is a series of "boot-strap" phases. The general idea is covered at [Installing GCC: Building](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html) and [Installation of GCC - LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html).

Comment: Different brand workstations in the 1980s and early 90s had their own unix-like environments with c compiler, tools, etc... that were all a little bit different from each other.  With the GCC source you could do an initial compile of gcc on one of these platforms, and then compile gcc with itself a few times to more or less check for a fixed point.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The specific history to gcc is given at the [GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/History). The more general point is that compilers are generally originally compiled with some other compiler until they are powerful enough to compile themselves. Alternately, it is possible to write a basic compiler that can handle a subset of your features in assembler, and build up from there. But again, this is almost never needed anymore. There are plenty of compilers available, in a variety of languages. Even when Stephen Johnson was writing pcc (one of the first C compilers), there were compilers for B available, along with many other languages. gcc had several compilers to pick from to build it originally, and RMS says he was using the Pastel compiler at least during his initial development.

Remember, there is no requirement that a C compiler be written in C. You could write it in Perl if you wanted to. There is no requirement that a compiler for a given platform be originally written on that platform (embedded systems almost always are compiled on some other system). So there are many ways to get yourself bootstrapped.

This question has some interesting subtleties related to the first instance of bootstrapping the compiler. If you were very clever, you could make use of that bootstrap to do [something incredible, brilliant and terrifying](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/04/15/strange-loops-dennis-ritchie-a/).

Comment: Thanks for the great bootstrapping link. I had assumed that compilers were always written in simpler languages all the way back to machine code for *sort of* this reason. (For example, what if you realise that the binary for your compiler contains a mistake? This provides a much stronger example of course.) So what are the advantages of writing the compiler in it's own language language? Do extremely paranoid people worry about this and build their compilers without "self" bootstrapping?

Comment: Some language groups consider it a mark of honor to be able to compile themselves. Go recently made a big push in this direction. Swift, on the other hand, notably has no current plans to rewrite their compiler in Swift. Note however, that GCC was always written in C. It just was compiled with other compilers. But if all C compilers were written in BCPL, that wouldn't fix anything regarding paranoia. It just moves the issue back one step. (You'd get the same paranoia benefits by just compiling GCC w/ clang.)

Comment: Note that gcc has a policy that gcc major version X can always be compiled with gcc major version X-1, so any new features added to the compiler in X can only be used in the gcc source itself from X+1. e.g. you should be able to compile any gcc version 9, no matter what the minor version number is, with any gcc 8, again no matter what the minor version is.

Comment: Adding to that, if you wanted to truly, provably solve the paranoia problem, you'd have to [find the bottom turtle](https://blog.dave.tf/post/finding-bottom-turtle/).

Answer (score 56):

Originally it was written in some assembly language then it began to dog food itself.

Comment: I haven't seen any references to RMS using assembler for the original bootstrap. What's your source for that? He had several other compilers to bootstrap with, so that seems a lot of work.

Comment: I though the term was bootstrap.

Comment: hahaha I read this a few weeks ago and thought you were out of you mind with that expression, didn't realize it was standard. Good Show sir ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food

Answer (score 4):

While this is obviously just a very rough indicator, I found this quick **listing** on the `gcc-5.1.0-src/gcc/` directory interesting. This directory 
contains the main sources of GCC itself (except for runtime libraries).

Here are the **top file-counts** (over 100) grouped **by extension** dominated by C and C++ files.

```
    112 .opt
    118 .def
    140 .cc
    185 .x
    250 .exp
    353 .md
    366 .mm
    414 .f
    430 .f03
    521 .m
    625 .a
   1082 .go
   1371 .h
   1602 .ads
   1655 .adb
   1828 .ada
   3860 .f90
  11231 .C        // C++ 
  23811 .c        // C
```

Please note that nowadays `GCC` refers to the GNU Compiler Collection, not just the GNU C Compiler.

> **6.3 The gcc Subdirectory**
>
> The gcc directory contains many files that are part of the C sources
>   of GCC, other files used as part of the configuration and build
>   process, and subdirectories including documentation and a testsuite.

*Reference:* https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/gcc-Directory.html

Comment: Note that [even `.c` files in GCC contain C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55906430/995714) because developers didn't rename the file when they migrate to C++

Answer (score 3):

> Is gcc C compiler written in C itself?

No, [gcc has been migrated to C++ since 2010](https://lwn.net/Articles/390204/). For more details read
[GCC's move to C++](https://lwn.net/Articles/542457/)