# Can a language be written in itself?

Tags: recursion, programming-languages

Would it be possible to structure a language in such a way that it can be written in itself? Could you write a c compiler in c, or a python interpreter in python? And if not, could the source then be re-written in itself? If so, would you have to use any components of another language (ie run compiled c in a python script)? Have there been any examples of this in actuality?

Comment: The Mono C# compiler is written in C#..

Comment: Yes. It's called "[bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers))".

Comment: FYI, PyPy is a Python interpreter in Python. gcc and g++ were written in C for a long time and are now written in a mix of C and C++.

Comment: Yes, it is customary for compiled languages to have a compiler written in themselves. You don't need components of another language in this compiler -- but you do initially need an auxiliary interpreter or compiler written in an existing language.

Comment: The basic answer is no. Of course, if a compiler already exists for a language, you could then use that compiler to write another compiler for that language in that language. This is as obvious as the fact that you can write programs in that language with a compiler, therefore, that does not count. Another reason that does not count is this compiler or one its predecessors could not be written in that language. So no, you cannot actually build a compiler in the language the compiler is made for because this requires the compiler to already exist, which if it did, you would not need to make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key word you are looking for is [self-hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting).

> Other programs that are typically self-hosting include kernels,
>   assemblers, shells and revision control software.
>
> Programming languages which have been self-hosted include Ada, BASIC,
>   C, CoffeeScript, F#, FASM, Forth, Haskell, Java, Lisp, Modula-2,
>   OCaml, Oberon, Pascal, Python, Scala, Smalltalk, and Vala.

One more compiler not on the list that I have worked with is [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/).

And the related term [Self-interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-interpreter).

> There are some languages that have a particularly nice and elegant
>   self-interpreter, such as Lisp or Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

[Is gcc C compiler written in C itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657454/is-gcc-c-compiler-written-in-c-itself)

It just requires predecessor. At some point someone wrote a compiler without a compiler in asm. 
I would assume.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one approach is to write a [metacircular interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacircular_interpreter), which has the advantage that it is very easy to understand or write a simple one. Probably the most well-known textbook example of this is chapter 4 of [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), which explores implementing a subset of Scheme in itself. Although if you'd like to learn about interpreters and programming languages in general, I think [PLAI](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/) is a better place to start.

For a production language, you often want more than a simple interpreter, but you can still bootstrap the implementation at some point. For a recent example, the [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/) compiler is written in itself.