# What are Vectors and < > in C?

Tags: c, gcc, vector, compiler-construction

I was looking at the source code for [gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c) (out of curiosity), and I noticed a data structure that I've never seen in C before.

At line [80](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c#L80) and [129](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.c#L129) (and many other places) in the parser, they seem to be using vectors.

```
80:  vec<tree> incomplete_record_decls;
129: ridpointers = ggc_cleared_vec_alloc<tree> ((int) RID_MAX);
```

I've never encountered this data type in C, nor these: `< >`. Are they native to C?

Does anyone know what they are and how they are used?

Comment: Since file has `c` extension it should be C. Maybe this is some kind of gcc extension? Like some C specific features are available for C++ (VLA) in gcc, maybe this works also in other way.

Comment: Are you sure the file extension is `.c` with a *lower* case `c`? Not an *upper* case `C`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Its lower case. If you go to [the gcc git repo](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/gcc/c), everything seems to be writen in C. I got this from c-parser.c

Comment: `vec` is defined in gcc/vec.h. It's a c++ template class.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I recollect that GCC have changed a few years back to build itself all with the C++ compiler. Perhaps they just haven't come around to rename all the files yet? See e.g. [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/542457/) about the details of the change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC has moved from C to C++ since GCC 4.8

> GCC now uses C++ as its implementation language. This means that to build GCC from sources, you will need a C++ compiler that understands C++ 2003. For more details on the rationale and specific changes, please refer to the [C++ conversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-conversion) page.
>
> [GCC 4.8 Release Series - Changes, New Features, and Fixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)

The work has actually begun long before that, with the [creation of `gcc-in-cxx` branch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-06/msg00385.html). The developers first tried to compile the source code with a C++ compiler, so there weren't any name changes. I guess they didn't bother to rename the files later when [merging the two branches](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=2b15d2ba7eb3a25dfb15a7300f4ee7a141ee8539) and officially have only one C++ branch

You can read [GCC's move to C++](https://lwn.net/Articles/542457/) for more historical information

Comment: So if I understand correctly, C has now some Object Oriented properties ? Is this considered proper C coding, and should it be used in industry ?

Comment: no, C is still C. There's no class or template in it. It's just the **GCC compiler is written in C++**. The compiler and the language are different things

Answer (score 10):

Despite the .c filename, this code is not valid C; it is C++, using that language's [template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) feature.  If you inspect the gcc build process, you will find that this file is actually compiled with a C++ compiler.

https://gcc.gnu.org/codingconventions.html

> The directories gcc, libcpp and fixincludes may use C++03. They may also use the long long type if the host C++ compiler supports it. These directories should use reasonably portable parts of C++03, so that it is possible to build GCC with C++ compilers other than GCC itself. If testing reveals that reasonably recent versions of non-GCC C++ compilers cannot compile GCC, then GCC code should be adjusted accordingly. (Avoiding unusual language constructs helps immensely.) Furthermore, these directories should also be compatible with C++11.

Keep in mind that although compilers will usually *by default* infer a source file's language from its filename, this default can always be overridden.  It is entirely possible to have C++ code in a .c file, or C code in a .bas file for that matter; you just may have to tell the compiler some other way what language is in use.

I expect that gcc chose this file naming convention because this code was originally written in C and later converted to C++, and they found it too much of a pain to change all the filenames.  It would mean a lot of work to update all the makefiles, etc.  It may have been less of a pain to just change which compiler was used, and to explain the convention to all the developers.  Of course, in general it is better programming practice to name your files in the standard way, but apparently the gcc developers felt it was not the best course of action in this case.

Comment: Whereas I agree that the code seems to be C++, it's still odd that the file uses an extension that normally identifies files as containing C source, as opposed to C++.  The excerpt from the docs does not explain that oddity; in fact the emphasis on supporting C++ compilers other than GCC seems like it would point to avoiding such unconventionalities.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes, it is odd. I assume it's historical: the code was originally written in C and later started incorporating bits of C++ as they were useful, and presumably they thought changing all the filenames would be too much of a pain.  I doubt it's a serious problem for supporting other compilers; just a matter of a command-line option to tell it what language to use.